# Is there any handler on the change of window url location in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a form in my html code. I need to confirm if the user wants to save the current form when they are about to redirect *accidentally* (by clicking on links, or clicking on the back button of the browser, etc)

I know GMail has a solution for this. It confirms whether I want to save my new mail as draft when I was leaving the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually want the `onbeforeunload` event, which will ask your user to confirm whether they want to navigate away or not:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    return "Are you sure you want to leave this page?";
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload